# set the source port on UDP Socket without using Bind?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp

Is there a way (in the .NET framework) to set the source port on a UDP packet without using the Socket.Bind call? This particular socket only sends data. I'm using the SendTo method that takes the remote address and port. I don't want to bind to anything. However, my client software uses the source port of the UDP packet for the return path.

Comment: You don't need to set it. A source port will be allocated automatically on the first send if it isn't already bound. But if this socket only sends data why do you care? It should receive the response as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Setting the source address and port is the whole purpose of the bind call. Why would you want to avoid calling it? What is it that you think that binding the socket does that you don't want to do?

No, there does not exist a second/alternate way to set the source address and port. Binding the socket is the one and only way to do that.

Comment: Some of the other posts on SO seemed to indicate that there was a performance gain if I was to use separate sockets for sending and receiving data. In no circumstance can I have a send block a receive or vice-versa.

Comment: What is the bind call doing with the address parameter? It seems that it should just take a port.

Comment: This "performance gain" claim surprises me... or else it only applies in some specific context and I don't have in mind what that context is. Anyway, there's absolutely no reason why a receive should ever block on a send or vice versa.

Comment: bind takes an address and a port and sets the local end of the socket to that address and port (or to any address if the address is `INADDR_ANY`)

Comment: @Brannon There is no performance gain, just a waste of resources. Your 'other posts' are mistaken.